# Links are display into two rows (React, css)

Tags: css, reactjs, header, navbar, nav

I have some `Header`:

```
<header>
 <div>                              
  <Link to="/" class="navbar-brand">Home</Link>
  <Link to="/test" class="navbar-brand">Test</Link>
  <Link to="/test2" class="navbar-brand">Test2</Link>
  <Link to="/test3" class="navbar-brand">Test3</Link>
 </div>
</header>
```

Into `css` I got only this:

```
header {
  background: rgb(73, 176, 236);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

When I tried to display it into `phone` it looks like `links` are into 2 rows.

It's possible to somehow make it smaller that will be display into one line?

Screen from phone:

[image]

Comment: how do you mean into phone ? I don't get  it

Comment: can you add a screenshot or maybe a fiddle ?

Comment: sure, please see update - I when I open my webSite on phone it's looks like on picture

Comment: It would be great if you gave me a fiddle, but try this: ' flex: 1 0 auto ' on header selector

This will prevent your flex container from shrinking, however if you want to display those texts better, I'd suggest you set your fonts with rem, there are many other solutions I can think of as well.

Comment: ok - you put this two as answer: I mean flex and add please `rem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to prevent your flex container from shrinking:

```
header {
  background: rgb(73, 176, 236);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 0 auto
}
```

Moreover, for a better UI, you can aim for relative units such as `rem`. Which is the base font size of the agent (16 px on most browsers).

```
font-size: 1rem;
```

and then change the base font depending on the viewport:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
      font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

this will allow you to scale, as all the `rem` units you've utilized for selectors will now increase and decreased accordingly.

Comment: Im just starting way with css/react, as Im mostly focus on backend - C#/Oracle

Comment: I understand... this is an interesting space to explore :)